# "ORA-00913: too many values" error when I run SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ora-00913

I'm getting a "too many values" error and I'm not sure how to approach it. The problem starts at the first nested SELECT

```
SELECT p.name, p.phone_number 
    FROM person p WHERE 
    (SELECT ks.title, ks.ks_code 
    FROM required_skills rs JOIN knowledge_skills ks USING (ks_code) 
    WHERE rs.pos_code = 'CS1') 
    IN (SELECT ks.title, ks.ks_code 
        FROM courses_taken ct  JOIN course_learning_units clu 
        USING (c_code)  JOIN learning_unit_skills lus USING (lu_code) 
        JOIN knowledge_skills ks USING (ks_code))
```

I looked up [info about this error](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00913.php) and I believe it's because the subquery in the WHERE returns too many columns. The table data is below. But how can I whittle that down? I appreciate any pointers, Thanks

**required_skills**

```
POS_CODE    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes     1   
KS_CODE VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes     2
```

**learning_unit_skills**

```
LU_CODE VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes     1   
KS_CODE VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes     2
```

**person**

```
PER_ID  NUMBER(38,0)    No      1   
NAME    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  Yes     2   
STREET  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  Yes     3   
CITY    VARCHAR2(60 BYTE)   Yes     4   
ZIP_CODE    VARCHAR2(60 BYTE)   Yes     5   
PHONE_NUMBER    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  Yes     6   
GENDER  VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)    Yes     7
```

**course learning units**

```
C_CODE  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes     1   
LU_CODE VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes
```

**courses taken**

```
C_CODE  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes     1   
PER_ID  NUMBER(38,0)    Yes     2
```

Comment: in your query  after the first where condition there is no field or column is mentioned

Comment: How are your other tables related to `person`?

Comment: @MichałPowaga - Thanks - yes, it's by a courses_taken table

Comment: The subquery (preceding the IN operator) does not return "too many columns" but it returns too many rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick rewrite:

```
SELECT p.name, p.phone_number 
    FROM person p WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
    FROM required_skills rs JOIN knowledge_skills ks USING (ks_code) 
    WHERE rs.pos_code = 'CS1'
      AND (ks.title, ks.ks_code)
    IN (SELECT ks.title, ks.ks_code 
        FROM courses_taken ct  JOIN course_learning_units clu 
        USING (c_code)  JOIN learning_unit_skills lus USING (lu_code) 
        JOIN knowledge_skills ks USING (ks_code))
    )
```

or (the joins will probably need corrections):

```
SELECT p.name, p.phone_number 
    FROM person p WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
     FROM required_skills rs JOIN knowledge_skills ks USING (ks_code) 
        JOIN ( courses_taken ct  JOIN course_learning_units clu 
               USING (c_code)  JOIN learning_unit_skills lus USING (lu_code) 
              ) USING (ks_code)
     WHERE rs.pos_code = 'CS1'
    )
```

---

Problem is that in your code there is no relation to table `person`. I guess you should have one in the subqueries - making them correlated.

Comment: Thanks so much! This did it(I'm surprised how powerful a rewrite is)! Thank You Very Much

Comment: And thank you also for the alternate version - that helped a lot!

Comment: Are you sure your query is this? Because (without any condition between `person` and the other tables), it will either return all rows from `person` or none at all, depending on the `EXISTS` subquery outcome.

Comment: Yes, you're right - I was wondering about why it did that. The goal is to "List all the names along with the phone-numbers of the persons who are qualified for a position" . Would I need to add another condition at the end with the rs.pos_code = 'CS1'?

Comment: Well, you probably have a `person_code` in one of those tables, in `required_skills` perhaps or in `knowledge_skills`.

Comment: You may then add a `WHERE rs.person_code = p.person_code` in the subquery.

Comment: I think it may be `required_skills.ks_code = learning_unit_skills.ks_code` (to get people with necessary position skills) .  Thank You So Much!

Comment: I thought you had that already. Anyway, it's almost impossible for us to know what fields belong to which table, because you don't use `ON` but `USING`

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. So I'm guessing I should prefer the use of `ON` rather than `USING` ?

Comment: No, `USING` is more compact. If you prefer it, use it. But if you want us to understand better the structure, post the tables' definitions.

Answer (score 1):

use "exists" at the place of "in"  may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE EMP(EMPNO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
        ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
        JOB VARCHAR2(9),
        MGR NUMBER(4),
        HIREDATE DATE,
        SAL NUMBER(7, 2),
        COMM NUMBER(7, 2),
        DEPTNO NUMBER(2));


INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7369, 'SMITH',  'CLERK',     7902,
        TO_DATE('17-DEC-1980', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  800, NULL, 20);
```

while inserting values it is giving error to many values

I've a table script of this table when I insert it it gives lot of errors while on my desktop it works fine